# how do i achieve the format of a dataframe as shown below

Tags: python

how do i reshape my dataframe from

[image]

to
[image]

using Python

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John', 'Martin', 'Ricky'], 'Age': ['25', '27', '22'], 'Car1': ['Hyundai', 'VW', 'Ford'], 'Car2': ['Maruti', 'Merc', 'NA']})
```

Comment: Please, roll back the edit. Better show the dataframe as text rather than pictures.

Comment: Be sure to use an actual `nan` instead of `'NA'` or `.dropna` won't work

Comment: sure, i got it :) @Ashargin

Comment: If it's all good you can accept the answer to close the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want :

```
df_melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name', 'Age', 'salary'], value_vars=['car1', 'car2'], var_name='car_number', value_name='car')
df_melted.drop('car_number', axis=1, inplace=True)
df_melted.sort_values('Name', inplace=True)
df_melted.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Wow!!, that worked straight away. Thanks a lot @Ashargin :)